# Spark Chi-Square Feature Selection Performance

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I have some performance problems with Spark ChiSqureSelector algorithm.

I implemented feature selection as below:

```
private JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> chiSqure(JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> orginalData, int k) {
    ChiSqSelector selector = new ChiSqSelector(k);
    transformer = selector.fit(orginalData.rdd());
    return orginalData.map(lp -> new LabeledPoint(lp.label(), transformer.transform(lp.features())));
}
```

All works great but for 8000 vectors with dimension 15k each(and numberOfTopFeatures=14k parameter) chiSquare model fitting took about 15 minutes.

I need to use this function for original data size about 100k vectors with dimension about 100k each, so I'm worried about it can kill performance.

Am I doing something wrong?
How can I improve performance of ChiSquare model fitting?

My Test environment parameters
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo 3.0 GHz,
RAM: 8 GB

Answer (score 0):

Spark's performance capabilities generally come from running across multiple machines, so I wouldn't worry about any single machine benchmarks particularly. Overall your usage looks fine.

Comment: So could you recommend me any other library to feature selection with chi-square algorithm? I'm using for now only single machine environment.

Answer (score 0):

First you should verify the settings of your SparkConf, and consequently SparkContext (setup #cores,  executor & driver memory). Second, even on a single machine you can simulate a cluster with Spark. Take a look [here](https://mbonaci.github.io/mbo-spark/) for instance.